# Convert pdf file to xlsx in python

Tags: python

I used the library. First, I output a table from the pdf on certain pages. Then I go through all the rows in the table and add the row data to the sheet.

```
    import 
from openpyxl import Workbook

with pdfplumber.open("Pdffile.pdf") as p:
    workbook = Workbook()  # New blank Excel workbook
    sheet = workbook.active  # activation sheet
    for i in range(4,6):  # Traverse 4 pages-6 page
        page = p.pages[i]
    for row in table:  # Traverse all rows
        print(row)
        sheet.append(row)  # Append write data by row
    workbook.save("Excel1.xlsx")  # Save file named Excel
    print("The first%d page PDF Extraction complete" % i)  # Prompt extraction progress
```

But as a result, I get the last specified page, not all of it. I suppose the error is in the raw traversal. But in what way?

It is in the table that all the pages that are needed are displayed. But in raw, it's the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the answer in response to the comment by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15779351/nobody). Improved the table extraction by removing the hidden vertical lines. In order to preserve the structure of the table on pages where the leftmost column is missing, you can handle that by adding missing cells to that row on the left before writing to Excel. I have made the assumption that the desired number of columns is 6 and only the leftmost column will be missing. The updated code will become:

```py
import pdfplumber
from openpyxl import Workbook


def keep_visible_lines(obj):
    """If the object is a hidden line, remove it."""
    if obj["object_type"] == "rect":
        return obj["non_stroking_color"] == 0

    return True


with pdfplumber.open("Pdffile.pdf") as pdf:
    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    for page in pdf.pages:
        page = page.filter(keep_visible_lines)
        table = page.extract_table()

        for row in table:
            sheet.append(([None] * (6 - len(row))) + row)

        workbook.save("Excel1.xlsx")
```

**ORIGINAL**

The for loop for writing to the sheet is outside the page for loop. The following code will fix the issue.

```py
import pdfplumber
from openpyxl import Workbook

with pdfplumber.open("Pdffile.pdf") as p:
    workbook = Workbook()  # New blank Excel workbook
    sheet = workbook.active  # activation sheet
    for i in range(4,6):  # Traverse 4 pages-6 page
        page = p.pages[i]
        table = page.extract_table()  # Extract table data
        print(table)
        for row in table:  # Traverse all rows
            print(row)
            sheet.append(row)  # Append write data by row
        workbook.save("Excel1.xlsx")  # Save file named Excel
        print("The first%d page PDF Extraction complete" % i)  # Prompt extraction progress
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Can I ask you one more thing? If you output pages with the specialty direction number, for example, as on the first page 01.03.04, then when output in csv, the next page that does not have such numbers will be shifted 1 column to the left. Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: @nobody Yes, it is doable. I have edited my original answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oh, I get it. But is it possible to control which pages I want to display in this way?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can I specify which pages to output? Just based on your code, the entire pdf file is output.

Comment: Yes, you can. You may replace `pdf.pages` with `pdf.pages[start:end]` or go with the same `range()` approach that you are using in your question.

Comment: If I have answered your question, please upvote and accept is as the answer.

Comment: I have no reputation to vote. But ill accept it as the answer. Thank very much.